# How to detect shared objects loaded by python ctypes

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ctypes

I need to copy shared objects into a package for distribution.  Until this point, ldd was enough.

I've now encountered https://github.com/emcconville/wand/blob/master/wand/api.py which uses ctypes that ldd doesn't detect.

How can I detect what shared objects are loaded so that I can copy them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this in general. Consider a program that did `ctypes.util.find_library(sys.argv[1])`. You can't possibly know ahead of time what libraries it will try to load.

In your specific case, you should be able to figure it out by wrapping `ctypes` to log all of the libraries it loads during execution. Note, though, that this will only work if your execution loads all of the libraries that it will ever need on any execution, so make sure you hit all relevant code paths.